# How would I make a google search from a PHP page?

Tags: php, search

My goal is to take in a search term or two and echo back a link that would take you to a Google search for that term. I know that there is a way to do it using the URL, but every thing I come up on is **VERY** confusing lol.

Comment: Do you want to capture the search terms, or just send people directly to google?

Comment: For example, if someone has the words "Albert Einstein" in a field in the form. I want a link to appear that would take them to the google search results page for those terms.

I was thinking of maybe just using the "Let me google that for you" site since their URL searching is very easy to use.

Comment: Just declare this string somewhere as a variable - "http://www.google.com/search?&q=". Then you can tack on the search terms entered and percent-escape the whole string, then display it to the user.

Answer (score 3):

`echo "<a href='http://www.google.com/search?q=".urlencode($search)."'>".$search."</a>";`

Comment: That should be `'http://www.google.com/search?q=' . urlencode($search)` or the link will be broken for browsers with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @Boann Yea, I just did a quick google and copied the url. updated, thanks.

Comment: You can also add a target to the link, to open in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple redirector:

```
<html>

<body>
<form>
Enter search terms: <input type="text" name="search">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['search']) && ($_GET['search'] !== '')) {
    $search = urlencode($_GET['search']);
    echo <<<EOL
<a href="http://google.com/search?q={$search}">Click here to search for '$search'</a>

EOL;
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why does this have a down vote? It answers the question exactly...  (except there's no submit button on the form)