# How to make a google search from text input

Tags: php, html, web

I know that the topic has been covered before here but what i saw ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882109/how-would-i-make-a-google-search-from-a-php-page)) has a problem which is that if there are any spaces in the search it will search it like this "Why+am+i+awesome" where the "+" are spaces, is there a way to fix this?

Side note: this might be some silly question but i'm just learning to program, so i'm taking anything that comes into mind and trying to make it happen, so any suggestions of what i could try to do will be kindly appreciated (in PHP, HTML, C++, and i want to try java).

Comment: That's how the browser interprets spaces. If you have in your URL `?id=Why+am+i+awesome`. If you use `$_GET['id']` you'll have `Why am i awesome`. That's just how your browser interprets it. You can't remove it nor fix it

Comment: In addition to what @Hearner said, maybe read up on URL encoding in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to remove the + from the string?
Tell us what you're trying to achieve here, since Google works with the URL including the +

Anyway, to remove any + signs from a string try

```
<?php
$string = 'Why+am+i+awesome';
$string = preg_replace("/\+/", " ", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that when it does the search it searches for "Why+am+i+awesome" but i cant delete the + because you cant use them in a url...